# How to get the output of a SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql

This is just for learning purpose. I want to get all the usernames and passwords from a table in a MySQL server, where "magic quotes" have been disable. In the input for the username: I put something like:

```
username'; SELECT * FROM users;
```

But how can I get the input of my injection query? I did some research, how can I do it in MySQL? Or is there a better way? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check some good examples in MySQL injection attacks here.

http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/13045/